# Refactoring. Copy paste code when code differs by only one line

Tags: java, web-applications, refactoring, legacy

I have a class called `FirstClass` and it has one method which has over 100 lines. Now I am writing a new class called `SecondClass` which has a method that is exactly like the method in the `FirstClass` except for one line.

I can copy the content of the `firstMethod()` and paste it in `secondMethod()` and just change the line that differs. But this doesn't seem right to me.

How do I go about handling this situation without doing copy/paste of code?

**FirstClass cannot be changed.**

```
public class FirstClass {
    public void firstMethod() {
        //100 lines of code
    }
}

public class SecondClass {
    public void secondMethod() {
        // Copy/paste the content of firstMethod() from above?
    }
}
```

Comment: A 100-line method is already bad design in most cases, so it's not like you'd be the first to do something that's not optimal in that codebase.

Comment: While I agree with @Kayaman, that doesn't mean you should be the next to add non-optimal code. Sounds like some refactoring is in order.

Comment: Why can't "FirstClass" be changed? Is it part of a third-party library?

Comment: It all depends on the code. Legacy code is legacy code, so in the worst case you're wasting your time trying to "put make up on a pig", in the best case you'll get a little bit prettier pig. Especially when you have arbitrary "class X can't be changed" constraints.

Comment: @cjstehno Can't change the "FirstClass" becuause the mantra is "It's a working code and don't change anything that's working"

Comment: Wow. Well if you refractor it ccorrectly it will still be working code. That's always seemed a sad excuse.

Answer (score 1):

Use a abstract class with the common code and extend it and then overide the method by calling the super method and executing the different code:

```
public class CommonClass {
    public void method() {
        // 100 lines of code
    }
}

public class FirstClass extends CommonClass {
    public void method() {
        super.method();
        // other code
    }
}

public class SecondClass extends CommonClass {
    public method() {
        super.method();
        // other code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option in this case would be a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).
[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm) you can see a Java-based implementation.

```
public class SecondClass extends FirstClass {
    private FirstClass firstClass;

    ...

    @Override 
    void firstMethod() {
        // do something before
        firstClass.firstMethod();
        // do something after
    }
```

But 100 lines of code in a single method doesn't seem right for me.

Answer (score 1):

> **FirstClass cannot be changed.**

That requirement is very limiting.  If you can't change the first method at all, then I can see only two possibilities.

The first possibility depends on what the first method actually does, and what the second one is supposed to do.  If you're lucky, maybe you can write the second method so that it;

- Maybe sets up some special conditions or special environment,
- Calls the first method, maybe in some special way,
- Maybe fixes up the result in some way.

If you can't make that work, then the only other possibility I can see is cut/copy/paste/edit, and then go wash your hands.